# How to push to Github package registry with Gradle

Tags: java, maven, gradle, github-package-registry

Trying to push the Gradle project to Github package registry, but not working as expected.

Using `io.freefair.github.package-registry-maven-publish` plugin for Gradle.

Configure GitHub in `build.gradle` with data needed to publish - code below. And run the publishing task `publishAllPublicationsToGutHub`. Getting no error but I can't see my package in GitHub package registry.

```
github {
    slug
    username = "myGitUserName"
    token = "myTokenWithRightAccess"
    tag = "HEAD"
    travis = true
}
```

Expecting some examples of how to publish to Github package registry with Gradle or what I'm doing wrong when publishing

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**New answer**:

GitHub has published the official guide: [Configuring Gradle for use with GitHub Packages](https://help.github.com/en/github/managing-packages-with-github-packages/configuring-gradle-for-use-with-github-packages).

---

**Old answer**:

It seems like the plugin [is not very stable yet](https://github.com/freefair/gradle-plugins/issues/50). Take a look at [the repository I've created](https://github.com/madhead/so57323260) that has everything set up. I managed to publish a few packages with that plugin [here](https://github.com/madhead/so57323260/packages).

Even the packages are published, Gradle shows task as failed, due to some issues with `maven-metadata.xml`:

```
> Task :publishMainPublicationToGitHub madhead Maven PackagesRepository FAILED
Could not transfer metadata so57323260:test/maven-metadata.xml from/to remote (https://maven.pkg.github.com/madhead): Could not get resource 'so57323260/test/maven-metadata.xml'

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':publishMainPublicationToGitHub madhead Maven PackagesRepository'.
> Failed to publish publication 'main' to repository 'GitHub madhead Maven Packages'
   > Could not GET 'https://maven.pkg.github.com/madhead/so57323260/test/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 422 from server: Unprocessable Entity
```

But that's ok, probably will be fixed one day.

I've noticed, that the packages might not be published (see the [linked issue](https://github.com/freefair/gradle-plugins/issues/50)) because of the incorrect `groupId` of a Maven publication. It seems like right now it should be equal to the Github's project name. So, in my case, I had to use `so57323260` as a `groupId` for a `madhead/so57323260` project. That's not how packages work in Maven generally, so that might be your issue.

Comment: Thank you mate, it works for me, have the same error as you, on "3.8.2" version it doesn't work, have a different error. Expected that I need only provide "GitHub" block to make publish but I needed to add the "publishing" block and "maven-publish" plugin to make it works.

Comment: Yeah. Let's stay tuned on GitHub issues.

Comment: Have another question, how to access to Github package registry as a dependency now by Gradle and thanks again for answer?

Comment: @DOIT, on, SO it's a [good practice](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/321823) to ask new questions for... new questions. So, I've asked one for you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57373631/750510) (and replied as well!). Take a look.

Comment: In your example, I keep getting this error... `madhead` is not a valid gradle task, am i doing something wrong here.

Comment: It just looks like this feature is too beta. I was able to publish with version x.y.z. Then I was not able to publish next version. Then I was able to publish when I removed version at all. Then I'm not able to publish anymore at all :)

Comment: The gotcha in our case was the `groupId` and `version`  in the `publications.gpr` block

Comment: The "New answer" answer is not self contained, you can't just link to an article on StackOverflow. Downvoted.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to publish to the Github Package Registry using the maven-publish plugin. It seems to work just fine now.

My build.gradle file looks like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'maven-publish'
}

group 'com.company.project'
archivesBaseName = 'library-name'
version '0.1.0'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  // java dependencies
}

publishing {
    repositories {
        maven {
            name = "Github"
            url = uri("https://maven.pkg.github.com/<OWNER>/<REPO>")
            credentials {
                username = findProperty("github.username")
                password = findProperty("github.token")
            }
        }
    }
    publications {
        register("jar", MavenPublication) {
            from(components["java"])
            pom {
                url.set("https://github.com/<OWNER>/<REPO>.git")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Put your github username and token into the gradle.properties file.

Comment: You should not put you GitHub token into the `gradle.properties` in the repository. The token is a secret that must not be public to other uses.

Comment: you should put the gradle.properties file in ~/.gradle/gradle.properties

Answer (score 3):

Also worth setting up a github action to publish to the github package repo:

```
name: Publish package to GitHub Packages
on:
  release:
    types: [created]
jobs:
  publish:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: 1.8
      - name: Publish package
        run: gradle -Pversion=${{ github.event.release.tag_name }} build publish
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

This publishes a package every time we create a release tag with that tag as the version.

Comment: Could you please share your `bulild.gradle` file so its easy to cross-reference

Comment: this is years ago, I no longer use this solution. But it's probably a variation of what @jjoller did

Answer (score 1):

GitHub has published the official document for How to use Gradle with GitHub packager

https://help.github.com/en/github/managing-packages-with-github-packages/configuring-gradle-for-use-with-github-packages#authenticating-to-github-packages

Answer (score 1):

Complete those properties correctly

1. OWNER
2. REPOSITORY
3. USERNAME (or gradle property `gpr.user`)
4. PASSWORD (or gradle property `gpr.key`)

@See demo

1. https://github.com/youngerier/packagesdemo
2. https://help.github.com/en/github/managing-packages-with-github-packages/configuring-gradle-for-use-with-github-packages

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the token I had setup in repo secrets had permissions only for `repo`. Beware, it should have `write:packages` authorized to it also in https://github.com/settings/tokens/new