# How to add GitHub Package Registry package as a Gradle dependency

Tags: maven, gradle, github, github-package-registry

So, I have a [GitHub project](https://github.com/madhead/so57323260) with a Package Registry configured. It has two packages:

[image: Two packages published in Github Package Registry]

Package pages have instructions only for Maven, besides that, the instructions are broken (`maven install so57323260` is not a valid way to add a dependency in Maven):

[image: Package page with broken Maven instructions]

Question is: how do I add [that package](https://github.com/madhead/so57323260/packages/14541) in a Gradle build?

Comment: Your repository project page says ~"**No packages published**"

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky, that's because I cleaned up all my unsed packages several times.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**New answer**:

GitHub has published the official guide: [Configuring Gradle for use with GitHub Packages](https://help.github.com/en/github/managing-packages-with-github-packages/configuring-gradle-for-use-with-github-packages).

---

**Old answer**:

First, configure Github Package Registry as a Maven repository in your Gradle build config:

*build.gradle.kts:*

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven("https://maven.pkg.github.com/madhead") {
        credentials {
            username = "madhead"
            password = "<token>"
        }
    }
}
```

You can generate a token in your [account settings page](https://github.com/settings/tokens).

Now, add a dependency like:

*build.gradle.kts:*

```
dependencies {
    implementation("so57323260:so57323260:1.0.0")
    implementation("so57323260:test:1.0.2")
}
```

Here `groupId` is the repo's name and `artifactId` is the name of the published package.

Comment: It's not possible to depend on a public package on GitHub Package Registry without hardcoding someone's GitHub username and token in the build file, is it?

Comment: Why "hardcoding"? You can keep the values in properties file or in the environment and get them with `System.getenv` or `System.getProperty`

Comment: Still, that's significantly more work for anyone else trying to just clone and run a project with dependencies that publically exist on GitHub Package Registry as opposed to Maven Central or jCenter. I was hoping there wouldn't be such totally unneeded limitation, forcing everyone to set up some GitHub-specific stuff just to automatically make use of JARs that are accessible publically.

Comment: This does not seem to work for me. Either my packages but also your example package won't be found by gradle.

Comment: Are there any security concerns letting your own username and read-only token in gradle property file?

Comment: it only works with `gradle install` for me, not refreshing the gradle in IntelliJ. Also my IntelliJ project doesn't find the "Library" class: https://github.com/madhead/so57323260/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/by/dev/madhead/playgrounds/so57323260/Library.kt

`gradle install` doesnt find my package https://github.com/ttiganik/hrd-java-test-registry/packages/60280 with `implementation 'hrd-java-test-registry:test-registry:1.0-snapshot'` and maven("https://maven.pkg.github.com/ttiganik")

Comment: "Could not get unknown property 'java' for SoftwareComponentInternal set of type org.gradle.api.internal.component.DefaultSoftwareComponentContainer."

Comment: Should we follow your **old answer** or **new answer**?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky, follow the docs. I think these question and answers are outdated.

Answer (score 6):

For those who are worried about the **security** of personal access token, the official guide suggests to access the username and password through Gradle property or system property.

Step1: Set USERNAME and TOKEN as system property (with `export` or `set`), or create a `gradle.properties` file under the project root folder like this:

```
gpr.user=<USERNAME>
gpr.token=<TOKEN>
```

Step2: Add the Github package registry with authentication in build.gradle:

```
    repositories {
        maven {
            name = "GitHubPackages"
            url = uri("https://maven.pkg.github.com/OWNER/REPOSITORY")
            credentials {
                username = project.findProperty("gpr.user") ?: System.getenv("USERNAME")
                password = project.findProperty("gpr.token") ?: System.getenv("TOKEN")
            }
        }
    }
```

Step 3: Add the package you want to consume in build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.example:package:version'
}
```

For more details (including how to config Maven), see the instructions in the Wiki I contributed here: https://github.com/GumTreeDiff/gumtree/wiki/Getting-Started

Comment: We don't need to hardcode **gpr.user** and **gpr.token**.  Github already stores those securely for us, and we just need to do:
`System.getenv("GITHUB_ACTOR")` and `System.getenv("GITHUB_TOKEN")`

Comment: doesn't work any more with the latest maven built-in studio plugin https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76565326/task-generatemetadatafileforreleasepublication-uses-this-output-of-task-androids